# objective c delegate understanding

Tags: objective-c

I have a class ApiClient which gets some data from a server using NSURLConnection and sends it back to its delegate

I have another class called Fetcher.h that calls some function on ApiClient and implements the  delegate method in it.

I have a third class (View Controller) that calls the Fetcher.h executeCall() and triggers the whole process.

```
    Fetcher *fetcher = [[Fetcher alloc] init];
    [fetcher getData];
```

If I call the ApiClient code directly in the View controller, it works fine. Why wont it work from the Fetcher class? What am I doing wrong?

Within the Fetcher getData I have this code

```
APIClient* client = [APIClient sharedInstance];
[client setDelegate:self];
[client getData];
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: everything works fine except the Fetcher's delegate never gets called if I call Fetcher from the ViewController.

Comment: if I call ApiClient directly from ViewController, the delegate gets called fine.

Comment: How are `-[Fetcher init]` and `-[Fetcher getData]` implemented?

Comment: Do you have some more code to show? Where are you setting the `Fetcher` as the delegate of the `ApiClient`?  Delegates aren't magically established by implementing the protocol's methods, you need to actually set the object as the other's delegate

Comment: added code that goes in Fetcher class

Comment: @Chuck Fetcher is just a simple subclass of NSObject and implements the delegate method of ApiClient. In my ViewController's viewDidLoad, I call the Fetcher using the code shown above. Hope that answers your question.

Comment: I think you need to provide more code. How does the protocols and the properties look like? Like Dan says it isn't magic and you left out the important parts!

Comment: How does `APIClient` call the delegate method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible that since you are not assigning the `Fetcher` object you are creating in the viewcontroller to any property or anything, it is getting released at the end of whatever method you are allocating it in.  Try adding this to your viewcontroller:

.h

```
@interface ViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) Fetcher *myFetcher; //Add this line in your view controller's interface
...
```

.m

```
@implementation ViewController

@synthesize myFetcher;
...
Fetcher *fetcher = [[Fetcher alloc] init];
[fetcher getData];
self.myFetcher = fetcher;//Add this line in your code as well
```

Comment: Thanks, that was it! it needed a strong property in the .h file. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
@protocol APIClientProtocol <NSObject>
@optional
- (void) handleMessage;
@end

@interface APIClient : NSObject
@property (readwrite, nonatomic, strong) id<APIClientProtocol> delegate;
@end

@implementation APIClient
@synthesize delegate;

- (void) someAPIClientWork 
{

   // Do some client work here

   if ( [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(handleMessage)] )
      [self.delegate performSelector:@selector(handleMessage)];
}

@end
```

.h of Fetcher

```
@interface Fetcher : NSObject <APIClientProtocol>
@end
```

.m of Fetcher

```
@implementation Fetcher

- (void) someInit 
{
   APIClient *client = [APIClient sharedInstance];
   client.delegate = self;
}

- (void) handleMessage 
{

   // Something in APIClient was called
}

@end
```